# Get the regular price of variable product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I found a lot of answers, but none works for a variable products. I would like to display both, sales price and regular price for variable products.

```
global $product;
if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
    $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
}
$regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
```

This is working, but only if it is a normal product. I think there must be a possibility even for product variations, but I don't find it.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For prices in variable products you need to use different methods specific to [`WC_Product_Variable`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html) Class. A variable product is made of multiple **product variations**, so the prices of a variable product are its product variations prices.

You can get the min or the max prices of a variable product like:

```
global $product;

// Regular price min and max
$min_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min' );
$max_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max' );

// Sale price min and max
$min_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min' );
$max_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max' );

// The active price min and max
$min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min' );
$max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max' );
```

For a variable product, the method `is_on_sale()` **will return true** if one of it's product variations is on sale…

You ca also use the method [`get_variation_prices()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html#_get_variation_prices) that will give you a multidimensional array of all the product variations prices (active, regular and sale prices) set in the variable product.